# Помощь с .gitignore

Tags: git

Гит не исключает эти папки. Как их записать правильней?

```
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/.idea/
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/p052.iml
```

Comment: Покажите `git ls-files -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/` и `git status -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/`

Comment: DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Controller.class
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Main.class
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/sample.fxml
это певрое

Comment: На ветке master
Ваша ветка обновлена в соответствии с «origin/master».

нечего коммитить, нет изменений в рабочем каталоге
//это второе

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае:

```
git ls-files -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/
```

вывел

```
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Controller.class
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Main.class
DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/sample.fxml
```

Команда `ls-files` показывает, что указанные файлы уже отслеживаются гитом и вошли в коммит(ы).

Чтобы увидеть этот коммит(ы), выполните `git log -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/` - поймете когда их закоммитили.

```
git status -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/
```

Эта команда показывает текущее состояние этих файлов (у вас изменений нет).

Теперь решение.

Чтобы исключить эти каталоги, нужно для каждого сделать такую операцию:

```
git rm -r --cached -- DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/
```

Она удаляет рекурсивно (`-r`) все файлы из каталога `DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/`, а опция `--cached` предназначена для того, чтобы файлы остались на диске, но были удалены из-под контроля гита.

Для единичного файла опцию `-r` не надо указывать, так как это не каталог:

```
git rm --cached DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/p052.iml
```

После этого сделайте `git status`. Выведется примерно такое сообщение:

```
Изменения, которые будут включены в коммит:
  (используйте «git reset HEAD <файл>…», чтобы убрать из индекса)

  удалено: DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Controller.class
  удалено: DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/Main.class
  удалено: DZ_from_books/Java_Tom1/p052/out/production/p052/sample/sample.fxml
```

Но эти файлы на диске должны остаться. Теперь нужно закоммитить изменения: `git commit -m "удаление случайно закоммиченных файлов"`.

Но! В истории гита эти файлы останутся, и их можно будет посмотреть и восстановить. Просто они перестанут отслеживаться гитом. Если в этих файлах содержатся какие-то секретные данные, то нужно переписать историю.

Делается это с помощью `git rebase -i HEAD~10`, где 10 - это то число коммитов, которые нужно переписать. Как это сделать написано [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Эта операция немного опасна в неопытных руках, но ее можно отменить через просмотр `git reflog`, например это описано [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/git-tips-and-tricks/).

Теперь, если `.gitignore` написан верно, `git status` не должен показывать в новых файлах эти каталоги и файлы.

Comment: Вроде бы в фале проекта и бинарниках секретной информации быть не должно?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мало ли, я не силен в Java. Ну и для будущих посетителей SO, чтобы у них сложилось верное представление.